# Functions Lebesgue integrable over set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have the following question

> State whether the function $f$ is Lebesgue measurable over $E$.
>   Justify your answers, and calculate $\int_E f$ in those cases where
>   this is feasible.
>
> i) $E = (0, \pi/2)$, $f(x) = \tan(x)$
>
> ii) $E = [1, \infty)$, $f(x) = (-1)^n/n$ if $n \leq x < n+1$, $n =
> > 1,2,...$

With i), $f(x)$ is continuous on the interval $E$ so it is measurable. However, it isn't bounded so we can't immediately conclude it is Lebesgue integrable. I'm stuck here as to how to go about showing whether or not this is Lebesgue integrable.

ii) isn't continuous, however, am I right in thinking that $\int_E f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n/n = -\log(2)$? If so, what rigorous justification is there for this?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i)
A simple calculation shows that
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{tan}(x)\mathrm{d}x = - \mathrm{ln}(\mathrm{cos}(\frac{\pi}{2})) + \mathrm{ln}(\mathrm{cos}(0))  = \infty
$$
So although $\mathrm{tan}(x)$ is measurable, it is not Lebesgue integrable.

ii)
It would make sense to assume that $\int_E f = - \mathrm{ln}(2)$. (For the Riemann integral this actually is true.) However such definition has problems that become more evident when functions of two or more variables are involved. To avoid these problems function is Lebesgue integrable only if its absolute value is Lebesgue integrable. Now the integral becomes
$$
\int_E |f| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow \infty 
$$
which is the harmonic series and thus diverges.

Comment: Think you mean diverges, in the last sentence

Comment: @lamiaani Thanks. I wasn't aware that you could just go straight into the integration with i) and show it diverges to show it isn't Lebesgue integrable. Also thanks with ii) I did actually know $f$ is Lebesgue integrable if and only if $|f|$ is, so I should've got that one. Thanks again.